# Reapplying for Australian tourist visa with my successful US visas?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia, jordanian-citizens

I am a Jordanian citizen. My application for Australian tourist visa was denied. I provided bank account and work letter. Everything was ok but I haven't travelled in the past 5 years so I checked as "no". I've actually been to the United States and I came back to my country 4 years ago.

My refusal letter has the following text:

> **Information Considered**
>
> I am a delegated decision maker under Section 65 of the Migration Act
>   1958 (the Act). In reaching my decision, I have considered the
>   following:
>
> - relevant legislation contained in the Act and Migration Regulations 1994 (the Regulations) collectively “migration law”;
> - information contained in the department's Procedures Advice Manual 3;
> - documents and information provided by the applicant(s); and
> - other relevant information held on departmental files.
>
> **Reasons for Decision**
>
> Under migration law, an application is made for a
>   class of visa and your application must be considered against the
>   criteria for all subclasses within that visa class. Your application
>   has been considered against the criteria for the following subclasses
>   within VISITOR visa class.
>
> 600 - VISITOR
>
> I have assessed the application and the reasons for my decision are
>   detailed below.
>
> A valid application for a Visitor- Tourist stream visa has been made
>   by the applicant. Under the migration law, a visa cannot be granted
>   unless the applicant meets the relevant legal requirements that are
>   specified in the Act and the Regulations. Clause 600.211 has not been
>   met by the applicant on the date I made my decision:
>
> Clause 600.211 states that:
>
> > The applicant genuinely intends to stay
> >     temporarily in Australia for the purpose for which the visa is
> >     granted, having regard to:
> >
> > (a) whether the applicant has complied substantially with the
> >     conditions to which the last substantive visa, or any subsequent
> >     bridging visa, held by the applicant was subject; and
> >
> > (b) whether the applicant intends to comply with the conditions to
> >     which the Subclass 600 visa would be subject; and
> >
> > (c) any other relevant matter.
>
> In assessing whether or not you intend a genuine temporary stay, I
>   have taken into account the information provided in the visa
>   application and all supporting documents relating to your personal
>   circumstances, commitments, incentive to return home and your
>   financial situation. I have considered the evidence supplied in your
>   application. I have considered your funds. I have considered your
>   family composition in Jordan. I have considered your evidence of
>   employment. I have considered you have provided no evidence of
>   previous compliant international travel. After considering the
>   information you have provided as evidence of your purpose in visiting
>   Australia, I am not satisfied that you genuinely intend to visit
>   Australia temporarily. Therefore, I am not satisfied that you have met
>   the legal requirements in clause 600.211 of Schedule 2 of the
>   Regulations.
>
> **Decision**
>
> As you do not meet one or more clauses in Schedule 2 of the
>   Regulations, I find that you do not meet the criteria for the grant of
>   a VISITOR (Class FA) VISITOR (Subclass 600) visa. Therefore, I refuse
>   your application for a VISITOR (Class FA) VISITOR (Subclass 600) visa
>   lodged at Amman.

So if I attached my US visas will it be possible to get a visa? Or do I need to travel around before reapplying or will none of these work?

Comment: The US and Australia are two different countries. It's completely irrelevant that one gave you a visa and the other didn't. If it weren't, the US would not have given you a visa because you didn't get one from Australia.

Comment: @jwenting I believe The OP is specifically focussing on this line from refusal letter `"I have considered you have provided no evidence of previous compliant international travel"`

Comment: @james aban How long were you in the US for? Why didn’t you include that, given that you returned to Jordan 4 years ago?

Comment: @RedBaron yes, where is meant travel to and from Australia only (and maybe New Zealand)

Comment: @jwenting Why would they write "compliant international travel" if they meant "compliant travel to Australia" or "compliant travel to Australia and New Zealand"? Please give some evidence for your claims, because they really don't make much sense.

Comment: @jwenting When you are in a hole, stop digging. Your assertion is totally without merit. `compliant international travel` means exactly that without you embellishing or garnishing it.

Comment: I WENT TO THE US IN 2011 BUT CAME BACK TO JORDAN IN 2014 THAT'S WHY I DID NOT INCLUDE IT. I THOUGH T THIS TRIP IS BEFORE WHAT THEY ARE ASKING ALSO I WENT TO THE US TWICE BEFORE THIS ONE AS A STUDENT

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided enough information that would convince the Australian government that you intent to leave the country after before your visa is to expire.

They're not going to look at other countries letting you in, their standards may be lower.
Had you had previous visa for Australia and you didn't violate those, those would have been taken into account but those apparently don't exist.

So you have to be a lot more convincing that you actually plan to return to Jordan before the Australian visa you're applying for it to expire.
Apparently the officer does not think your current job and family situation, and/or your financial situation, give you enough incentive to leave Australia when needed.
That could for example be because you're single and only holding a low paying job or no job at all.

It's pretty hard to change those things of course. An immigration lawyer might be able to help you reword your application to improve your chances, but of course at a cost and with no guarantee it will work.